# New to Visual Studio Code and C, experiencing difficulty with it

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm just started doing C in my class and wanted to try Visual Studio Code as my way to code my C code. I tried to write a simple hello world program just to make sure everything is working, but I get this error message saying "Access is denied" and can't do anything beyond that. I've gotten both the run extension and installed Mingw to build/run my code. Any advice/recommendations on how to fix this issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");

    return 0;
}
```

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\Trey\projects\helloworld\" && gcc main.c -o main && "c:\Users\Trey\projects\helloworld\"main
Access is denied.
```

Here's an image just in case you wish to check the code for any gap errors.[image]

Comment: Try saving the files in different folder, on your desktop, or start in administrator mode.

Comment: Did you try to run VS Code as Administrator?

Comment: Why would you need to use administrator mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it appears you are on Windows, compiled programs must end in `.exe`

Change your build command to be:

```
gcc main.c -o main.exe
```

So that the output file is an *executable*.

As it is, your output file is `main`(no extension), so when you try to run it, Windows does not know if it is an executable, or a Word Document or a MPG movie file.

Comment: I tried this and although at first, it had two successful runs, it then went back to deny me access even though nothing had changed

Comment: It... Just works now, I know this fix this, but it didn't work for a bit... concerned... STILL THANK YOU THOUGH!!!

Comment: If you're previously created an executable called `main` rather than `main.exe`, be sure you remove the `main` file. If you try to run the command `main`, it might try to invoke either `main` or `main.exe` if both exist (or even `main.somethingelse`, for example `main.bat` if you happen to have a file by that name). Or invoke it explicitly as `main.exe`.